# Changing Specific URL / Meta Details For Social Media

Tags: facebook, metadata, social-networking, meta-tags

I have a website, which is split up into various sections, and I'm using facebook to share / promote my content.

The problem is that facebook seems to pick up the primary URL and publish that on all posts that I make - Here's an example:

[image]

In this example, facebook picks out that it's on the URL `Soundcloud.com`, but is there a way of actually changin what is displayed here?

As my website is split into sections, with each section being a sub business, I'd like that to display the relevant business name as opposed to the primary URL. Can this be done?

Currently I use `<meta name="author" content="My Name">` to display the name displayed to the right of the URL, so I was wondering if these Meta Tags could be used to change what goes where the URL is!

Comment: That is not the actual URL that is used, that is only the site name. `og:site_name`

Comment: So @CBroe, if I place `<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Business Name" />` beneath the Author Meta tag, I should see `My Business Name | By My Name` on all facebook posts?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site Name">` to reflect on all pages that you would want with the site name you want.
If you're planning to share a SoundCloud URL, then you cannot do that unfortunately, you can only do that on your own website where you will have access to change such information.